What was the first game to implement Aim Down Sights (ADS)?
A lot of modern shooter games have an Aim Down Sights (ADS) feature, which allows you to be more accurate and see things that are farther away when aiming, all at the press of a button.
I’m curious to know what the first game that had ADS is.

If mods count, Infiltration for UT had proper ADS/iron sights, but appears to have been released in 2004. The version for Unreal might predate Flashpoint, but the "ADS" was just lifting the gun up a bit (and enabling the crosshair) and not moving it to the center of the screen. I have no idea when that was released, however.

I was disappointed to find that this isn't a question about advertisements (also called ads).

@SkySpiral7 Ah, should have thought of that. That would be an interesting question though.

As a feature/dedicated action (with firing from the hip as the default) it seems Operation Flashpoint: Cold War Crisis from 2001 takes the cake.
Technically similar is the ability to use a scope in addition to firing from the hip, the introduction of which is attributed to GoldenEye 007 from 1997:

GoldenEye 007 has been credited with pioneering and popularising the now-standard inclusion of scoped sniper rifles in video games.

It actually had a dedicated Aim Mode which closely resembles ADS, even including making character control less responsive.
Of course, there are older video games that had hardware that allowed for physical ADS. A light gun was available for the first video game console, the Magnavox Odyssey from 1972, a type of controller that is probably best known from the famous Duck Hunt from 1984. But I guess that's not what you're after.

GoldenEye 007 was the first things I thought of. Second thought was how the heck could OP have not thought about that game. Final thought, the game is almost 30 years old so now I need an ibuprofen and a nap.

@MonkeyZeus I have never heard of that game (GoldenEye 007) before this answer was posted. And why would I be assumed to know about it anyway?

@Daemons I'm not sure how serious that remark was. In any case it doesn't make sense to assume anyone would just think about that game, let alone make that connection. It is a classic and influential game, however, in the same vein as Doom, Wolfenstein, and Deus Ex are. But as MonkeyZeus points out, they grew up with those games, and some people simply didn't for whatever reason.

Thinking a bit outside the box, I don't recall if Silent Service from 1985 had zoomed aiming but similar genres like combat flight games maybe had it.

@Amarth Yeah, I'm also pretty sure using a scope had been introduced earlier, but to both be able to use a rifle from the hip and zoom in (what the OP was asking for) seems to have been introduced by GoldenEye. For some older games you had no other option but to zoom in before shooting. (That distinction might not have been clear in my answer, though.)

@Daemons Sorry, my comment's intent wasn't to try and belittle anyone. It was meant to be a joke at my expense =)
